# JSON Error? - Unfolding library - Bug or something else?

Tags: geojson, java, error

While trying to make use of GeoJSONReader from the Unfolding Library, while compiling I got the following error:

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{'
JSON Error: Expected a ':' after a key
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 28 [character 29 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.data.GeoJSONReader.loadDataFromJSON(Unknown Source)
....
A JSONObject text must end with '}'
JSONObject["features"] not found.
JSONObject["features"] is not a JSONArray.
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And it goes on...
First, I thought it had to do with the JSON itself so I tested via several JSON web validators and it looked fine. I even compared it to another JSON that I knew was working when I used it. And actually,there is no problem with it as it can be displayed on geojson.io, as in the SS.

[image]

Now, I'm not sure whether I did something wrong but I'm pretty sure this is the way to load up a GeoJSON/JSON.

```
List<Feature> busLine = GeoJSONReader.loadDataFromJSON(this, "mures/linia4_linie.geo.json");
```

Link to the [json](https://gist.github.com/masterflorin/919281d0e4b2d2ee014ec6c12296b909) gist

Any ideas?

**Specs:** using Unfolding library from [here](http://unfoldingmaps.org/) in Eclipse Mars, JDK 1.8.0_91

I've used it more than several times already but never had this issue before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was an actual bug in version 0.9.6, an older version which I was using.

Solution: git clone or ask for a newer version at least 0.9.8 beta.

You can read more in the issue opened on [GitHub](https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding/issues/131).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you used the 'loadDataFromJSON' method.
You can use the method 'loadData' instead of the above one. This will not give the error.